# Notepad++ Regex how do I replace characters but only when between double quotes

Tags: android, regex, notepad++

I'm looking to replace all the underscore (`_`) characters between the first pair of double quotes (`"`) with full stops (`.`) in this .xml

I've used this regex `android:name="([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)"` and got the selection `android:name="com_android_contacts"`, but how do I change the `_` into `.` within this selection?

```
<package-redirections android:name="com_android_contacts" android:resource="@xml/com_android_contacts" android:minSdkVersion="16" />
```

to

```
<package-redirections android:name="com.android.contacts" android:resource="@xml/com_android_contacts" android:minSdkVersion="16" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(?:android:name="[^"_]*)\K_([^"_]*)
```

And replace with `.$1` as many times as necessary until there is no more replacements.

Make sure you have opted for the regular expression search. I'm not sure about version differences, but this works on v6.1.8.

This works for any number of dots in the `android.name` attribute.

`\K` resets the match so that you don't have to put back `android:name`

---

Btw: In PCRE flavoured regex, you can use this:

```
(?:android:name="[^"_]*|\G)\K_([^"_]*)
```

Which replaces in a single replace all the underscores to dots.

`\G` matches at the end of the previous match.

Comment: oh nice. Seems I learn new thing \K :) only one note. If regex forgets everything before \K so maybe we don't need ?:

Comment: @Darka Yup, there's no need for `?:` but I usually just use it in case the regex is modified.

Comment: second regex makes me think :D so it is possible to do in one replace

Comment: @Jerry. Awesome. the second regex is works wonderfully just with a single click.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can replace at once in notepad++,
but if you say if has only 2 _ then you can use this:
find

```
(android:name="[^"\._]*)(_)([^"\._]*)(_)([^"\._]*?")
```

replace to:

```
\1\.\3\.\5
```

Answer (score 0):

If all lines look like this (i.e. three elements with _ as delimiter) you could try 
Search:

```
(android:name="[^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^"]+")
```

Replace:

```
$1.$2.$3"
```

Explanation:

The values in brackets () are saved in variables calles $1, $2 and $3 (from left to right)
[^_] = all characters that are not _

In your example $1 = android:name="com
The following _ is to be replaced by a .
etc.

Comment: This one works, but in some conditions there is some android:name that only only contains or 1 _ or more than 3 _  this regex will overlap to the next attribute which should remain unchanged. Jerry's regex wrap it in the attribute. PS= it should be only .$3 without "